# Append combobox values from textbox using a button

Tags: python, list, tkinter, combobox, append

Using Python I have created a frame with empty ComboBox, TextBox and a Button. My ComboBox values are taken from List acitivity_list which initialy is empty. I am looking for a solution where user can insert a text into a TextBox and append the List activity_list so it appears in ComboBox by clicking the Button.

I failed implementing the append() function to update the List. My goal is to have a functionality where I write the name of activity in the TextBox, click the 'Add' Button and it appears in my ComboBox.

Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Activity:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("database")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        title=Label(self.root, text="Daily Activities Database", font=("Calibri",40,"bold"))
        title.pack(side=TOP)

#ComboBox 
        activity_list = []
        Frame1=Frame(self.root,bd=4, relief=RIDGE)
        Frame1.place(x=20, y=75, width=355, height=560 )
        combo_activity=ttk.Combobox(Frame1, font=("Calibri",20))
        combo_activity["values"]= activity_list
        combo_activity.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
#Textbox
        txt_act=Entry(Frame1, font=("Calibir",20))
        txt_act.grid(row=11, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
#Button
        bt1 = ttk.Button(Frame1, text = "Add")
        bt1.grid(row=12, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

root=Tk()
ob=Activity(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an instance method which is triggered when <kbd>Add</kbd> is clicked.  In the function, add the user input into `activity_list` and then update the `values` option of `combo_activity`.

However, you need to change some local variables to instance variables, otherwise they cannot be accessed inside the new function:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Activity:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("database")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        title=Label(self.root, text="Daily Activities Database", font=("Calibri",40,"bold"))
        title.pack(side=TOP)

        Frame1 = Frame(self.root,bd=4, relief=RIDGE)
        Frame1.place(x=20, y=75, width=355, height=560 )

        #ComboBox 
        self.activity_list = []
        self.combo_activity = ttk.Combobox(Frame1, font=("Calibri",20))
        self.combo_activity["values"] = self.activity_list
        self.combo_activity.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
        #Textbox
        self.txt_act = Entry(Frame1, font=("Calibir",20))
        self.txt_act.grid(row=11, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        #Button
        bt1 = ttk.Button(Frame1, text="Add", command=self.add_activity) # added command option
        bt1.grid(row=12, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

    def add_activity(self):
        activity = self.txt_act.get().strip()
        if activity:
            self.activity_list.append(activity)
            self.combo_activity["values"] = self.activity_list

root = Tk()
ob = Activity(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help. I have adjusted the code like this and the button disappeared for the frame. Perhaps there is something wrong with indentation?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Activity:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("database")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        title=Label(self.root, text="Daily Activities Database", font=("Calibri",40,"bold"))
        title.pack(side=TOP)
     
#ComboBox 
        activity_list = []
        Frame1=Frame(self.root,bd=4, relief=RIDGE)
        Frame1.place(x=20, y=75, width=355, height=560 )
        combo_activity=ttk.Combobox(Frame1, font=("Calibri",20))
        combo_activity["values"]= activity_list
        combo_activity.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
#Textbox
        txt_act=Entry(Frame1, font=("Calibir",20))
        txt_act.grid(row=11, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
#Button
def add_task(self):
        activity = txt_act.get()
        activity_list.append(activity)
        return activity_list
    
        bt1 = ttk.Button(Frame1, text = "Add")
        bt1.grid(row=12, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, command=add_task)


root=Tk()
ob=Activity(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This space is for answers. Consider posting further questions in repl.it